# Rhino, adding code from multiple javascript files

Tags: java, javascript, scripting, rhino

I am embedding some javascript in a Java application using Rhino. I am following the example on the Rhino website, executing a script by calling the Context's evaluateString method and passing the actual script in as a String.

I have a whole bunch of existing javascript code that I would like to make use of. I don't want to concatenate it all into an enormous String and pass it in to evaluateString. I would rather be able to load the code in so that I can call it from the code that I do pass into evaluateString (kind of like the AddCode method works in Microsoft's scripting control). I would like to add code like I can currently add variables by using the ScriptableObject.putProperty method.

Is there a way to do this? Can someone provide a code snippet or a link to the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Put all your javascript code in one file. Read the file into a `StringWriter` and use its `toString` method. Now use `evaluateString` to parse the entire javascript code and return a `Scriptable` object. After that you may simply use the `get(String namespace,Scriptable jsObject)` method of Scriptables to access any object in scope.

Comment: Just a remark: if you want to enable a continuation-passing-pattern (like you stated) you will need to have all relevant functions within scope and declare that scope in `Function.call(Scriptable context,Scriptable scope,Scriptable thisObject,Object[] args)`. Therefore, I don't really see the benefit of splitting your code into fragments.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Rhino_documentation/Scopes_and_Contexts) and [examples](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/examples.html) it looks like references to previously evaluated objects are controlled by [scopes](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/Context.html#evaluateReader(org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable,%20java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.Object)).

```
Context context = Context.enter();
try {
  ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();
  Object out = Context.javaToJS(System.out, scope);
  ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "out", out);
  context.evaluateString(scope,
      "function foo() { out.println('Hello, World!'); }", "<1>", 1, null);
  context
      .evaluateString(scope, "function bar() { foo(); }", "<2>", 1, null);
  context.evaluateString(scope, "bar();", "<3>", 1, null);
} finally {
  Context.exit();
}
```

*(Rhino 1.7 release 2)*

---

I know some people use Rhino directly to get the latest version, but the [Java 6 implementation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-frame.html) can evaluate scripts like this:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");
engine.eval("function foo() { println('Hello, World!'); }");
engine.eval("function bar() { foo(); }");
engine.eval("bar();");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code I had that need (utility scripts and such), and I just simply concatenated them together in a giant StringBuilder and evaled it (Java 6). Its the only way since javascript can't do (without Java wrapper objects) otherJSScript.someUsefulFunction().